# change the Foreground color when hover on CommandBar SecondaryCommands in a Universal app

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a menu in the CommandBar SecondaryCommands, I have listed the Style [`CommandBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) but I didn't found the line that let me change the Foreground Color when hover on each Item in the menu.
this is my code:

this is my code for the CommandBar:

```
<CommandBar Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource commandBarStyle}}" >
            <CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#00a0e3" ></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                 </Style>
            </CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
          
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands >
                <AppBarButton Label="Info"
                          Foreground="White" Background="#00a0e3"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

commandBarStyle is the Default style of CommandBar for windows store apps,I have added those lines in the "AvailableCommandsStates" section:

```
 <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AvailableCommandsStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="BothCommands"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PrimaryCommandsOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowContentRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SecondaryCommandsOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PrimaryItemsControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00a0e3" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#00a0e3" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
```

but always I get Black foreground color when I hover on the SecondaryCommands items
thanks for help again

Comment: thanks nha for the edit :)

Comment: Please post your xaml yo solve the problem

Comment: You should override style for button, not for bar. You can find  PointerOver state in button style

Comment: @Archana I have updated my Post :)

Comment: @nikita, do you mean that I should implement a Style for each AppBarButton in the "CommandBar.SecondaryCommands"

Comment: @hanli, nearly, you can override one style for AppBarButton for all your buttons

Comment: Edit the default style of AppearButton for PointerOver visual state

Comment: yes @Archana that's what I will do thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should override style for button, not for bar. You can find `PointerOver` state in button style